# Formulae error for multiple IF statement

Tags: formula

I am trying to put the formule but I am getting the error at first 1440, that ) is missing.

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Status , "Blast Sent"),(Blast_Created_D_T__c)- Hand_Off_Approved_DT__c )*1440 ,
IF(ISPICKVAL(Status , "Blast Pending"), (NOW()- Hand_Off_Approved_DT__c )*1440, 0))
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need to close your if condition at last

```
IF(ISPICKVAL(Status , "Blast Sent"), (Blast_Created_D_T__c)- Hand_Off_Approved_DT__c *1440 ,
    IF(ISPICKVAL(Status , "Blast Pending"), 
        (NOW()- Hand_Off_Approved_DT__c )*1440, 0
    )
)
```